# open a jFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-8

I'm trying to open a `JFrame` which is in class **B** by clicking on a button which is present in Class **A**. I'm using JFrameForm in the project. How would I achieve this?

I tried using this code,it successfully opens the JFrame in Class **B** (JDBC_Trial) but doesn't close the existing one in class **A**

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     new JDBC_Trial().setVisible(true);

     }
     }); 
     // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: I suggest not using more than 1 JFrame. It's considered bad practice. Instead, try using a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: I also suggest posting some of the code that you have tried. We want to **help**, so you can **learn** not just do everything for you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.This i my first time in Stackoverflow.Sorry.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dispatch event allows you to choose what happens to the frame. Here I've closed it:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
JDBC_Trial p = new JDBC_Trial();
p.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: in your initialize() class

Answer (score -1):

Its not recommended, but it is possible:

```
Download download = new Download();
download.setDefaultCloseOperation(download.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
download.setVisible(true);
```

Just put that on the event you want to call it on.